# Cocoa/Objective-c 'system();' acting weird

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, terminal, applescript, system

I'm trying to run an applescript inside my Cocoa app using the system(); function - the string I'm passing to the function works in terminal and the applescript itself is fine, I think it has something to do with NSString - can anyone help?

```
        //add to login items
        NSLog(@"add to login");
        NSString *pathOfApp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *theASCommandLoginItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to make login item at end with properties {path:\"%@\"}'", pathOfApp];
        system(theASCommandLoginItem);
        NSLog(theASCommandLoginItem);
```

Here is the output:

> 2009-10-11 20:09:52.803 The Talking
>   Cloud Notifier[3091:903] add to login
>   sh: \340HH: command not found
>   2009-10-11 20:09:52.813 The Talking
>   Cloud Notifier[3091:903]
>   /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell
>   application "System Events" to make
>   login item at end with properties
>   {path:"/Users/csmith/Desktop/The
>   Talking Cloud Notifier/build/Debug/The
>   Talking Cloud Notifier.app"}'

At compile I also get a warning saying:

> warning: passing argument 1 of
>   'system' from incompatible pointer
>   type

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Bad

As newacct's answer already suggested you have to use a C-string instead of an `NSString` for the `system()` function.

### Good

Use `NSTask` instead.

### Better

More useful for you would be the [`NSAppleScript`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class:

```
NSAppleScript *script;
NSDictionary *errorDict;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *returnValue;
// multi line string literal
NSString *scriptText = @"tell application 'System Events'\n"
                        "make login item at end with properties {path:\"%@\"}\n"
                        "end tell";
scriptText = [NSString stringWithFormat:scriptText, pathOfApp];
script = [[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptText] autorelease];
returnValue = [script executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];
if (returnValue) {
     // success
} else {
     // failure
}
```

### Best

Have a look at [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/CustomLogin.html) on how to register your app to be a login item. There are even some examples.

Answer (score 4):

`system()` is a C library function and takes a regular C string (`char *`), not an `NSString *`.

You can convert the `NSString` into a C string by using something like `[theASCommandLoginItem UTF8String]`

Or you can use the Objective-C's own way of running commands, something like:

```
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/osascript"
                         arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-e",
                                                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"System Events\" to make login item at end with properties {path:\"%@\"}", pathOfApp],
                                                             nil]];
```